# exclude Activeadmin based on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Is there a way to exclude admin based on Rails.env? I fixed the initializer,routes and gemfile, but it looks like its still trying to register the resources.

I want a setup where the production env does not have active admin, but another environment does and is pointing to the same database. I need to maintain both of these in the same git repo.

Appreciate any help I can get... Thanks

Stack: Rails 4, activeadmin

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the routes unavailable to the engine in different env.

in your `config/routes.rb` file

add this

`ActiveAdmin.routes(self) unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'`

Comment: Yup.. did that..... and did the same in the initializer.... and used groups in the gemfile to do the same... no luck

Comment: I think putting it in the appropriate group of the gemfile is a better idea, rather than doing what I suggested. After modifying your gemfile, do a bundle install (it will recreate the gemfile.lock) post that, commit and deploy.

Comment: the problem seems to be in the files in the admin folder... looks like it tries to run them regardless... and cant find ActiveAdmin